# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\wys\wys\app\views\index\index.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-4

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
```

Trying to get property of non-object `(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\wys\wys\app\views\index\index.blade.php)`

```
http://Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine handleViewException
…\bootstrap\compiled.php9881
```

**error code is,**

```
$this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
```

Controller.php

public function editnewsandevents($neid)
    {
       $newsevents = ForumNewsevent::find($neid);

```
return View::make('editnewsandevents.editnewsandevents')
->with('newsevents',$newsevents);
```

}

public function update() {

```
$validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'neh'=>'required|min:2',
        'neb'=>'required|min:5',
    )
); 
if($validation->fails()) {

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()
    ->withErrors($validation);
} else {

         $user   = Auth:: ForumNewsevent()->neid;
        //$newsevents = Input::get('neid');
    $nheader = Input::get('neh');
    $nbody=  Input::get('neb');
  ForumNewsevent::where('neid', $user)
    ->update(array(
        'nheader'    =>  $nheader,
        'nbody' =>  $nbody

    ));
    return Redirect::route('addnewsandevents')->with
           ('success','you updated sucessfully.');
}
```

how to solve this problem?

```
$user   = Auth:: ForumNewsevent()->neid;// in this code
```

in routes.php page im using not Auth ...its prefix/editnewsandevents. i think this line of codes are wrong

can you correct this codes

Comment: Well your problem is in here. `View: C:\xampp\htdocs\wys\wys\app\views\index\index.blade.php` So go to that file and look.

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="put" action="{{URL::Route('update')}}"><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="neb" id="neb">{{ $newsevents->nbody }}</textarea><input type="text" class="form-control" name="neh" id="neh" value="{{ $newsevents->nheader }}">       <input type="submit" name="sub" value="update" class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="neid" id="neid" value="{{ $newsevents->neid }}">this is my index.php

Comment: My guess is that the ForumNewsevent with the specified ID doesn't exist. Try to `dd($newsevents)` before returning anything.